# White screen when starting activity with AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, animationdrawable

I have an application that has an introduction animation, the animation displays perfectly but when launching the app, a white screen with an actionBar (the activity with the animetion hides the actionBar in it's onCreate) shows up for a few seconds. After finishing the animation, an Intent takes place and changes the activity.
It doesn't throw any errors in the logcat, or causes any other problem whatsoever. What can be the problem?

My code:

```
    package com.tuneit.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.tuneit.R;


public class StActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
        Intent ant;
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("TRANSITION", "TRANSITIONED TO ST ACTIVITY");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startup);
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        ant = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.hide();
        animate();

    }
    private void animate(){
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnOthers);
        //imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);
        AnimationDrawable frame = (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();
        frame.setOneShot(true);
        frame.start();
        checker(frame);
    }

    private void checker(AnimationDrawable anim){
        final AnimationDrawable a = anim;
        int timeBetweenChecks = 300;
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                if (a.getCurrent() != a.getFrame(a.getNumberOfFrames() - 1)){
                    checker(a);
                } else{
                    startActivity(ant);
                }
            }
        }, timeBetweenChecks);
    }

}
```

Comment: Source code of MainActivity

Comment: It's there, StActivity is Main

Comment: What is there in the MainActivity.class?